# Error downloading Spanish model in Spacy

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I am trying to use Spacy using Spanish model.

```
from spacy.es import Spanish

nlp = Spanish(path=None)

doc = nlp(u'Hola me llamo Sergio y estoy probando la librería.')
sentence = next(doc.sents)
```

Executing the above script I got the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "spacy/tokens/doc.pyx", line 434, in __get__ (spacy/tokens/doc.cpp:9664)
ValueError: sentence boundary detection requires the dependency parse, which requires data to be installed. If you haven't done so, run: 
python -m spacy download es
to install the data
```

After that, in command line I run 'python -m spacy download es' and I got another error:

```
$ python -m spacy download es

    Compatibility error

    No compatible model found for 'es' (spaCy v1.8.2).
```

Has anybody download Spanish model succesfully? Am I following the steps correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download the spanish models with:

```
python -m spacy download es_core_news_sm
```

You can see the two different spanish model on:

https://spacy.io/models/es

Then, you load the model with:

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('es_core_news_sm')
doc = nlp(r"La casa es amarilla.")
```